# How to build HTML navigation breadcrumbs without using an add-on?

Tags: navigation

There exist some add-ons that permit to build navigation breadcrumbs, such as NavEE, Construct and Structure.

What could the best way to create HTML navigation breadcrumbs without using an add-on?

Is using multiple conditionals a good choice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on how your pages are constructed, have you looked at this Tutorial yet?

https://expressionengine.com/learn/smarter-breadcrumbs-with-layout-lists

Russ

Comment: Thanks for this tutorial, seems very interesting and more adequate that using conditional operators. I didn't know the DRY Template Layouts. I will test this solution.

Comment: I read the EE4  DRY Template Layouts documentation, easy to implement. The tutorial permit to build a nice breadcrumb system.